# Train dataset progressively using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, training-data, object-detection-api

can we train image data-set progressively,like my previous training dataset is created using 500 images but now i want add more images in to it.

Should we train old dataset using more images ?

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow there are [checkpoints](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoints) for this. You import already learned weights for an existing model and continue training on new (or existing) data. You can just add the new images to your dataset. For the repeatability of the training procedure it is useful to create a new record file. Of course you have to refer to the new record file during the training.

Comment: but is our model would overfit to the training data due to repeat the previous dataset training ?

Comment: there is the possibility of overfitting. So you have to look at your trained model, if it is not overfitting and then you can apply this. However, if you see  it is overfitting, I would suggest retrain the whole model